# How is cv_values_ computed in sklearn.linear::RidgeCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The reproducible example to fix the discussion:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale 

boston = scale(load_boston().data)
target = load_boston().target

import numpy as np
alphas = np.linspace(1.0,200.0, 5)
fit0 = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, store_cv_values = True, gcv_mode='eigen').fit(boston, target)
fit0.alpha_
fit0.cv_values_[:,0]
```

The question: what formula is used to compute `fit0.cv_values_`?

## Edit:

@Abhinav Arora answer below seems to suggests that `fit0.cv_values_[:,0][0]`, the first entry of `fit0.cv_values_[:,0]` would be

```
(fit1.predict(boston[0,].reshape(1, -1)) - target[0])**2
```

where `fit1` is a ridge regression with alpha = 1.0, fitted to the data-set from which observation `0` was removed.

Let's see:

1) create new dataset with first row of original dataset removed:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
boston1 = np.delete(boston, (0), axis=0)
target1 = np.delete(target, (0), axis=0)
```

2) fit a ridge model with alpha = 1.0 on this truncated dataset:

```
fit1 = Ridge(alpha=1.0).fit(boston1, target1)
```

3) check the MSE of that model on the first data-point:

```
(fit1.predict(boston[0,].reshape(1, -1)) - target[0])**2
```

it is `array([ 37.64650853])` which is not the same as what is produced by the `fit0.cv_values_[:,0]`, ergo:

```
fit0.cv_values_[:,0][0]
```

which is `37.495629960571137`

What gives?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the generalized cross validation, which is slightly different from ordinary cross validation. The cost function is still the same but different points are weighed differently. Please allow me to look into this more and then update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the Sklearn documentation:

> Cross-validation values for each alpha (if store_cv_values=True and
>   cv=None). After fit() has been called, this attribute will contain the
>   mean squared errors (by default) or the values of the
>   {loss,score}_func function (if provided in the constructor).

Since you have not provided any scoring function in the constructor and also not provided anything for the `cv` argument in the constructor, this attribute should store the mean squared error for each sample using Leave-One out cross validation. The general formula for Mean Squared Error is

[image: Mean Squared Error]

where the Y (with the cap) is the prediction of your regressor and the other Y is the true value.

In your case, you are doing Leave-One out cross validation. Therefore, in every fold you have only 1 test point and thus n = 1. So, in your case doing a `fit0.cv_values_[:,0]` will simply give you the squared error for every point in your training data set when it was a part of the test fold and when the value of alpha was 1.0

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

[Let's look - it's open source after all](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py#L1137)

The first call to fit makes a call upwards to its parent, _BaseRidgeCV (line 997, in that implementation). We haven't provided a cross-validation generator, so we make another call upwards to _RidgeGCV.fit. There' plenty of math in the documentation of this function, but we're so close to the source that I'll let you go and read about it.

Here's the actual source

```
    v, Q, QT_y = _pre_compute(X, y)
    n_y = 1 if len(y.shape) == 1 else y.shape[1]
    cv_values = np.zeros((n_samples * n_y, len(self.alphas)))
    C = []

    scorer = check_scoring(self, scoring=self.scoring, allow_none=True)
    error = scorer is None

    for i, alpha in enumerate(self.alphas):
        weighted_alpha = (sample_weight * alpha
                          if sample_weight is not None
                          else alpha)
        if error:
            out, c = _errors(weighted_alpha, y, v, Q, QT_y)
        else:
            out, c = _values(weighted_alpha, y, v, Q, QT_y)
        cv_values[:, i] = out.ravel()
        C.append(c)
```

Note the un-exciting `pre_compute` function

```
def _pre_compute(self, X, y):
    # even if X is very sparse, K is usually very dense
    K = safe_sparse_dot(X, X.T, dense_output=True)
    v, Q = linalg.eigh(K)
    QT_y = np.dot(Q.T, y)
    return v, Q, QT_y
```

Abinav has explained what's going on on a mathematical level -it's simply accumulating the weighted mean squared error. The details of their implementation, and where it differs from your implementation, can be evaluated step-by-step from the code

Comment: Thanks. I tried to signal this question to the modo for push to http://stats.stackexchange.com to no avail. Basically, I can see how this is computed (there are even some math explanation in the source code). The question is,  why are the numbers produced by GCV do not correspond to what they should by which I mean the naive version of the computation which I carried in the edit to the main question. For example, `R`'s lm.ridge uses another math formula (to fast compute the GCV) and there the results are in accordance with what they should be.